# MySQL "case as column" question in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, php

I'm setting up a new column with this case statement:

```
SELECT * , 
CASE t2.field_max_occupancy_value
WHEN  'one' THEN 1 
WHEN  'two' THEN 2 
WHEN  'three' THEN 3 
WHEN  'four' THEN 4 
WHEN  'five' THEN 5 
WHEN  'six' THEN 6 
WHEN  'seven' THEN 7 
WHEN  'eight' THEN 8 
WHEN  'nine' THEN 9 
WHEN  'ten' THEN 10 
ELSE 0 
END AS numfield
FROM field_data_field_rate_dates t1
LEFT JOIN field_data_maximum_occupancy t2 on t2.entity_id = t1.entity_id
WHERE t1.field_rate_dates_value <=  '2015-07-11'
```

When I run that query - it works just fine - and I see numfield in the output.

However - when I append something to the WHERE clause...

AND numfield >= 3

It tells me that numfield is an unknown column.

Any ideas as to why?  Is there a declaration I need to make somewhere?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Aliases can't be used in `WHERE`. There are couple workarounds.
1. Repeat `CASE` in `WHERE` as **oNare** suggests
2. Put `numfield >3` in `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` (works for Mysql only)
3. Rewrite  query to use inline view syntax :

```
SELECT a.* FROM 
(
SELECT * , 
CASE t2.field_max_occupancy_value
WHEN  'one' THEN 1 
WHEN  'two' THEN 2 
WHEN  'three' THEN 3 
WHEN  'four' THEN 4 
WHEN  'five' THEN 5 
WHEN  'six' THEN 6 
WHEN  'seven' THEN 7 
WHEN  'eight' THEN 8 
WHEN  'nine' THEN 9 
WHEN  'ten' THEN 10 
ELSE 0 
END AS numfield
FROM field_data_field_rate_dates t1
LEFT JOIN field_data_maximum_occupancy t2 on t2.entity_id = t1.entity_id
WHERE t1.field_rate_dates_value <=  '2015-07-11'
)a 
WHERE  numfield >= 3
```

Comment: Just a few suggestions. The workaround with `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` will work on SQL Server too. But I would suggest your solution too, as there isn't a code duplication and it's much better to read for everyone instead of repeating the code.

But just one addition: The explanation why it doesn't work. The reason why it doesn't work using the `WHERE` is quite simple. The `WHERE` clause will be evaluated and executed before the `SELECT`. Due to this reason, `WHERE` can't know that you rename some expressions to a new column `numfield`.

Comment: @Ionic:   SQLServer (at least 2008R2 ) gives an error if `HAVING` is used without aggregate function/group by :  "Msg 8121: [column] is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."  Or "Invalid column"...

Comment: Yes but he can group it. So there isn't a problem?

Comment: Sure he can. But in Mysql he doesn't have to...

Comment: Yes, but I just wanted to mention, that he can use nearly the same solution on sql server. :D

Comment: I like workaround #2.

Comment: Suggestion for workaround #4: add `WHERE (t2.field_max_occupancy_value NOT IN ('one', 'two') AND t2.field_max_occupancy_value IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: @Ionic: The HAVING workaround [**will not work**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3233cd/1) in SQL Server. In Transact-SQL, you can reference a column alias only in ORDER BY. The usual workaround since SQL Server 2005 is to use APPLY.</offtopic>

Comment: @Ionic You have saved my time. I have used the Having query and solved the problem thanks bro.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use column aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.

> Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE code is executed, the column value may not yet be determined.

Try running:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE t2.field_max_occupancy_value
        WHEN  'one' THEN 1 
        WHEN  'two' THEN 2 
        WHEN  'three' THEN 3 
        WHEN  'four' THEN 4 
        WHEN  'five' THEN 5 
        WHEN  'six' THEN 6 
        WHEN  'seven' THEN 7 
        WHEN  'eight' THEN 8 
        WHEN  'nine' THEN 9 
        WHEN  'ten' THEN 10 
    ELSE 0 
        END AS numfield
FROM field_data_field_rate_dates t1
LEFT JOIN field_data_maximum_occupancy t2 on t2.entity_id = t1.entity_id
WHERE t1.field_rate_dates_value <=  '2015-07-11' && 
    (CASE t2.field_max_occupancy_value
        WHEN  'one' THEN 1 
        WHEN  'two' THEN 2 
        WHEN  'three' THEN 3 
        WHEN  'four' THEN 4 
        WHEN  'five' THEN 5 
        WHEN  'six' THEN 6 
        WHEN  'seven' THEN 7 
        WHEN  'eight' THEN 8 
        WHEN  'nine' THEN 9 
        WHEN  'ten' THEN 10 
        ELSE 0 
        END) >=3;
```